# tikzlibrary not loading from local file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

For some reason [tikz-bayesnet](https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet) is not displaying constants properly (line 22 in [this file](https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet/blob/master/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex)):

```
\tikzstyle{const} = [rectangle, inner sep=0pt, node distance=1]
```

[Here is a link to an overleaf example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/snbmbvpbrpfn) which loads the library in preamble and includes the source file in the project root but the constants are still showing up without a rectangular node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet, fit, backgrounds, positioning, matrix,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,quotes}

\title{tikz example}
\author{mkarikom }
\date{April 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.7cm,y=1.8cm]

  % Nodes

  \node[obs]                   (X)      {$X$} ; %
  \node[latent, above=of X]    (T)      {$T$} ; %
  \node[latent, above=of T]    (theta)  {$\theta$}; %
  \node[const, above=of theta] (atheta) {$\alpha_\theta$};


  % Factors
  \factor[above=of X]     {X-f}     {Multi} {} {} ; %
  \factor[above=of T]     {T-f}     {left:Multi} {} {} ; %
  \factor[above=of theta] {theta-f} {left:Dir} {} {} ; %

  % More nodes
  \node[latent, right=of X-f] (phi)  {$\phi$}; %
  \node[const, above=of phi]  (aphi) {$\alpha_\phi$}; %

  \factor[above=of phi] {phi-f} {right:Dir} {} {} ; %

  \factoredge {theta}  {T-f}     {T} ; %
  \factoredge {atheta} {theta-f} {theta} ; %
  \factoredge {phi}    {X-f}     {X} ; %
  \factoredge {aphi}   {phi-f}   {phi} ; %

  \gate {X-gate} {(X-f)(X-f-caption)} {T}

  \plate {plate1} { %
    (X)(X-gate) %
    (T)(T-f)(T-f-caption) %
  } {$\forall 1 \leq i \leq n_d$}; %
  \plate {} { %
    (plate1) %
    (theta)(theta-f)(theta-f-caption) %
  } {$\forall d \in \mathcal{D}$} ; %
  \plate {} { %
    (phi)(phi-f)(phi-f-caption) %
  } {$\forall t \in \mathcal{T}$} ; %

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `rectangle` only sets the shape of the node, it doesn't mean the outline is drawn. Are you after `\node[const, draw, above=of theta] (atheta) {$\alpha_\theta$};`

Comment: By the way, it's better if you include the code in the question directly, rather than linking to Overleaf. If you edit/delete the project from OL, the question becomes much less useful. (You could also make the example at lot more concise and to the point, as far as I can tell all you need is a single node in the `tikzpicture` to demonstrate the problem, the rest is kind of just noise ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a bit vague, but as I understand it you want the outline of the node to be drawn. The `rectangular` option used in the `const` style only sets the shape of the node. Just like with other node shapes (e.g. `circle`), in order to actually draw the outline, you add `draw` to the node style.

Presumably you want this for all `const` nodes, so it would be best to modify the style with `append style`, like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\tikzset{
  const/.append style={
    draw, % draw outline
    inner sep=0.333em % add some space between node contents and outline
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[const] {$\alpha_\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstood I'll just delete this.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  I have edited the OP to incorporate your suggestions.